# uSQL Maximum Request Length Exceeded

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am attempting to collapse a large number of disparate files into a unified layout. There are roughly 3k files that I am collapsing down to 40 subject areas. My original design is 40 jobs, each outputting a single unified layout. I then decided to create them all at once. When doing so, I receive an Internal Server Error stating "Maximum Request Length Exceeded".

I am trying to understand what that max is and how I can work around it. I am new to Azure Data Lake Analytics and uSQL, so there may be an obvious path that I do not see. Maybe I can create the 40 jobs and execute them via a coordinating script? Looking for efficiency. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into one of the capacity limits for your account.  It's a little hard to tell with what you've shared.  More details on the ADLA quota limits can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-quota-limits